# Are the roots of this polynomial in the unit circle?

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers

Consider 
$$
P(X) = X^{n+1} - aX^{n} +aX -1
$$
with $a \in [-1;1]$.

> Show that the moduli of the roots of $P$ are $1$.

What I tried is

- I've noticed if $z$ is a root then $\frac{1}{z}$ is a root as well.
- I've checked:
- $X-a+aX-1 = (1+a)(X-1)$
- $X^{2} - aX -1 +aX = (X-1)(X+1)$
- $X^{3} - aX^{2} +aX-1$ is more subtle.

I don't how far this question could lead us but I know compelex analysis and basic algebra.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that polynomial $X^{n+1}-aX^n+aX-1$ has only roots of module $1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2991940/show-that-polynomial-xn1-axnax-1-has-only-roots-of-module-1) – found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24P(X)%20%3D%20X%5E%7Bn%2B1%7D%20-%20aX%5E%7Bn%7D%20%2BaX%20-1%24&p=1)